What are the chances of strong SEO recognition from SPA
I've been working on a financial tools site using Angular 16 with PrimeNG and PrimeFlex for the UI, and I'm hosting it with Vercel. The site is in the early stages but I am just trying to wrap my head around the connotations of using Angular being a SPA.
When I look at google lighthouse review, this seems to do well for the SEO section and google search has indexed pages. Pages have tags and scripts etc and every page on the site has a route (url). I think the problem is with crawlers, are they able to construct Javascript well rather than just consuming static html.
I cannot find a definitive answer, I am trying to avoid having to change technology late into the project rather than at the start, I could move over to next.js with good support for ssr, I feel angular have not had a great front for ssr.
Do I need to worry about any of this at all, and google will do fine on the SEO front? (https://www.friendlyfinanceguide.co.uk)

It sounds like you have a handle on the technical stuff to handle crawling from Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?.  How often does your content change?  Do you need new content indexed quickly?

I feel more confident now with understanding what crawlers will get their head around. Not so much changing, but dynamic, ie /salary-after-tax/xyz, this could be hundreds of routes. I have opted to use SSG, so the pages serve a html file super quick but then actual page JS kicks in properly, allows for good SEO and good user interaction. I think I asked this question as a third party seo audit tool I was using suggested none of the dynamic JS was getting picked up by their crawlers, safe to ignore, but opted to offer static html also just for SEO purpose which has worked well.
